# Is there any way to retrieve the records from database in bunches rather than whole?

Tags: java, sql, javabeans

my code retrieves an enormous amount of records which results in out of memory error. I am looking for a way to divide what I want to retrieve and process that data, clean the memory, retrieve the rest again..

I could use Rownum but I don't know for sure that for the next retrieval, it will consider only the remaining, non retrieved records.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: u need to use logic where you will maintain the last row retrieved , so for next retrieval you will use that rownum and get next set of records

Comment: You are using hibernate or jdbc?

Comment: If you execute SQL statements on your own, you can use the rownum to determine which block of entries you want to edit. If you want to be on the safe side, use an ORDER statement to order the result, prefereably use the primary key to order, as it is fast.

Comment: I tried using the rownum  with the order by.. I see that my query is now taking more time! Which I guess is because of the order by!

Comment: For instance, This is what I'm doing: select * from ( select * from employee order by emp_Id ) where rownum between 1 and 100

Comment: I am using jdbc  not hibernate

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to divide what I want to retrieve and process that data, clean the memory, retrieve the rest again.

You can use [ResultSet#setFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize%28int%29)

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for this ResultSet object.

Here is an [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/navigate-result-sets.htm) posted at tutorialspoint.